# Display array key when a certain value is given

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of values queried from a database, `$roundsarray`.

Another query returns a set of values which are some of the same in the array. However, rather than displaying the values, I want to display them as a key. 
My code is as follows:

```
$datarounds=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT eventID FROM results WHERE (eventID BETWEEN '$firstevent' AND '$lastevent') AND compId='$compId' AND teamId='$teamid' AND (eventSession='R' OR eventSession='R1' OR eventSession='R2' OR eventSession='R3') AND driverId='$driversource' ORDER BY eventID", $CONNECTW);        
while($row=mysql_fetch_row($datarounds))
{ 
    $roundid=$row[0];
    foreach ($roundsarray as $k => $value)
    {
        if ($roundid==$value) { $rounddisplay=$k+1; }

        $roundpack .= "$rounddisplay,";
    }
```

The `$datarounds` query provides the event ids, and what i am trying to do is to display that a specific event is the 3rd, 4th, 12th or whatever in the array (the `$k+1` is to account for the first value of the array being key 0).

However, `$rounddisplay` is always returned empty and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Thank you for any help!

Comment: I am not able to understand your question. Possible to re-explain?

Comment: Sure thing!

I have an array, $roundsarray, whose elements, when printed, are as follows:

([0] => Array ( [id]=>598) [1] => Array ( [id]=>602) [2] => Array ( [id]=>607)... and so on.

The second query, $datarounds, provides results like "602", "607" etc

I want to find a way to make it display, if the result is 602, "1", if it's 607, "2" etc.

Comment: You want to match the second array with the matched positions in the 1st array.

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala the second does not come as an array but as individual values. But yeah, i want to match the second results with the positions of the first array.

I have no idea how to, however!

Comment: Check out this link http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php use `array_search` to search for the keys and then map it into new array.

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala thank you - this should do the trick, but i still get blanks.

I am starting to think the problem may be in my original array.  I am making it like this but i fear it may be wrong.

 $roundstotal=mysql_query("SELECT id FROM calendar WHERE eventDate BETWEEN '$season_start' AND '$season_end' AND competition='$compId' AND tag!='T' ORDER BY eventDate ASC", $CONNECTW);
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($roundstotal)) {
  $roundsarray[]=$row;
 }

Comment: cant understand the code in comment can u update the question with the code?

Comment: It's alright - I had made the original query wrong but I have since amended it, and I was able to fix it with your array_search suggestion :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look for:  `array_search` to get the keys.

Check out this link [php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) use `array_search` to search for the keys and then map it into new array.